# Updating Knockout-Bound Kendo UI Grid Columns Collection

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, knockout-kendo

I'm using the [Knockout-Kendo.js](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/) library to bind a Kendo Grid with Knockout bindings. I've built a system that loads multiple datasources that each have their own set of columns assigned to them. I have everything working great with the exception of getting the new columns collection assigned to the Knockout bound Kendo Grid.

I've read a few ways to get the columns reinitialized but all of these require the grid to be destroyed and recreated. I'm not sure how I would go about this with the Knockout bound grid. I'm using the code below.

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="kendoGrid: gridOptions"></div>
```

Knockout/JS:

`self.SearchResults` and `self.GridColumns` are both observable arrays.

```
self.gridOptions = {
    data: self.SearchResults,
    columns: self.GridColumns
};
```

When I update `self.SearchResults`, the grid updates correctly. Updating `self.GridColumns` has no effect on the displayed columns in the grid.

If anyone can point me in the right direction on how I would get the columns collection updated and displayed in conjunction with using the Knockout binding provided by the library linked above I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: `self.gridOptions` should be an observable so the data binding will know when it has been updated. Upon updating a member, call `self.gridOptions.valueHasMutated()`. I'm just basing this on how things *should* work; I don't know how the binding actually *does* work.

Answer (score 0):

So, I just figured this out. Turned out to be really simple.

What I ended up doing was this:

1. Get a reference to the grid and the current grid options
2. Assign the updated `self.GridColumns()` computed to the options
3. Set the grid options to the updated options

   ```
       var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
       var options = grid.getOptions();
       options.columns = self.GridColumns();
       grid.setOptions(options);
   ```